# How to exclude substring with regex from a large list of strings more efficiently

Tags: python, regex, list, substring

I have a large list of strings (len > 1000000) which I'm trying to convert into a dataframe. Before that, I have to exclude some items which are numbers 20~22 digits long (e.g: 0000000011111216546546), since they are a problem for my dataframe.

I got this done with the following code, which I know it is not pythonic (and takes 20 minutes to run):

```py
for i in range(len(lines2)):
    if re.match(r'(?:(?<!\d)\d{20,30}(?!\d))', lines2[i]):
        exclusao2.append(lines2[i])

lines2 = [x for x in lines2 if x not in exclusao2]
```

Anyone here knows how to do this in a lower time?

Comment: Why not using just filtering list-comprehension `lines2 = [l for l in lines2 if not re.match(r"(?:(?<!\d)\d{20,30}(?!\d))", l)]
` ?

Comment: Do you want to check if a string is all digits and contains 20 to 30 chars? `lines2 = [x for x in lines2 if not (x.isdigit() and (len(x) >= 20 and len(x) <= 30))]`? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/a6KnYu).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and even better `... and 20 <= len(x) <= 30`.

Comment: Your example is actually a 15 digit number containing leading zero.  If that is the only kind of issue you have with input data, wouldn't it be better to strip leading zeros instead of ignoring otherwise valid content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slow because you're building a list and then using this just to check membership. Testing membership repeatedly from a list is inefficient.

Assuming you have 1% values to remove, this gives you 10k strings in `exclusao2`. Then for each of these you will test membership in your list comprehension. This is slow.

To improve your code you need to use a set.

```
exclusao2 = set()
for s in lines2:
    if re.match(r'(?:(?<!\d)\d{20,30}(?!\d))', s):
        exclusao2.add(s)

lines2 = [x for x in lines2 if x not in exclusao2]
```

But that's still not ideal.

You can use your test directly:

```
lines2 = [s for s in lines2 if not re.match(r'(?:(?<!\d)\d{20,30}(?!\d))', s)]
```

Even better, as your check is quite simple, avoid regexes, use string operations as suggested in comments:

```
lines2 = [s for s in lines2
          if not (s.isdigit() and (20 <= len(s) <= 22))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expressions and membership in an exclusion list, you should filter your list (or better yet the input it comes from) directly.

If you use translate (which is very fast) to convert all digits to zeros, then any number with 20 digits or more will become (or contain) a series of 20 zeros.  You can use `in` on that translated string to determine if the line should be kept or not:

```
nums     = str.maketrans('123456789','000000000')
longNum  = '0'*20
*lines2, = filter(lambda s:longNum not in s.translate(nums),lines2)
```

Comment: This however enables to test only one length. I haven't timed out but even if `translate` is fast I would not expect this to be more efficient than `isdigit()` (after translation you still have to compare again the full string) + a test on the length (`O(1)`).

Comment: Agreed.  I thought the lines could contain other data in addition to the oversized number.  So a "whole string" approach will indeed be more efficient (although I would suggest placing the size check first in the condition to leverage short circuiting)

Comment: Actually, the OP's regular expression (and my solution) would match on '1234567901234567890123.55' but a whole string comparison would not.  So there is a difference that may need to be taken into account (if that use case exists)